# How to get Kofia Hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I do not mean that I deserved a Kofia hat, but today I asked and answered questions, all of which have at least one upvote.

Are there another requirement for the hat?

> Kofia
>
> > first post between 12/26 and 1/1

Comment: Hrm I do believe the "first post" part of that means *first post on the site*. Not first post during that time period. You would have to go participate on a new site where you've never participated before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- It has to be the first post you did on a site. So if you've already left a question or answer on a site, you can't earn that hat for that site
- It has to receive an upvote, so score >= 1. Not sure if you'd still get the hat if you got say 1 downvote and then 1 upvote. Probably not. Probably need score of >= 1 when the hat awarding script runs.

Comment: What? So I spend the last 45 minutes on answering a question for nothing! How unfair. Somebody should have told me...

Comment: @rene It says it right there in the description..